# Computing the derivative of a smooth map which has real and complex variables as input

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I want to compute the derivative of the following map $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^2$, $f(x,z)=(f_1(x,z),f_2(z))$. If I compute its Jacobian, is it just simply given by the map $$
(v,w)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}\\0&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v\\w\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $v\in\mathbb{R}$ and $w\in\mathbb{C}$? I am asking this (basic) question since I am confused that some derivatives in the Jacobian are real derivatives, and the others are complex.